# Windows Multiple Touch Screens - Touch on Wrong Monitor

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, touchscreen

I've got a PC with 7 touch screens connected to it. I use the 'Setup' in 'Tablet PC Settings' to link touch to the screens.

What we have found is that after a number of reboots, we will begin to see touch appearing on the wrong monitor and it requires to be set up again.

We're in an environment where this needs to work across multiple reboots with remote support so it's not ideal that someone would need to touch the screens to re-associate them again. I checked the registry page for Digimon and it does not change if the touch is working correctly or incorrectly.

One thing we have found is that the touch screen monitors we have DO NOT have a serial number - so the EDID they present to Windows is identical. We have tried this test with 7 off-the-shelf Dell monitors and it works flawlessly.

Without putting some EDID emulators in line, does anyone have any other ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: does your GPU support seven screens?

Comment: Yep, all screens work and connect. 3 onboard outputs, 4 additional on GPU

Comment: that does not answer my question if they support it.

Comment: Yes, 7 supported