# multiple touch screens permanent configuration

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, touchscreen

I am trying to configure multiple touch screens in Windows 10,
and it is working as long as I don't shutdown the screens.
If I shutdown the screens, at power up the touch inputs are either not working or working on just one screen (mostly the wrong screen).

To recover I need to unplug and plug back the touchscreens and re-calibrate.

I have configured the power management of each HID :

- "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" is unchecked,
- "Allow this device to wake the computer" is checked,

And "USB Selective Suspend" is disabled.

My investigation shows that Windows 10 does not detect all the HID when I power up the touch screens, hence only one is working.

My question is  : Is there a way to permanently enable a HID in Windows 10 ? And have its configuration permanent as well ?

Related to : [Windows Multiple Touch Screens - Touch on Wrong Monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/1347393/windows-multiple-touch-screens-touch-on-wrong-monitor)

Comment: How are the screens connected?

Comment: @harrymc One is HDMI, the other is display port, touch screen is USB on both